# trouble formating dates on R

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have the following code and message of error, as I am working currently on a time series of electricity production (per month). I need the format of the first column to be a date but when I run the code, it becomes a list of NAs instead...
Could anyone help ?

Here is the code I tried which transformed the column date into a list of NAs :

```
 test_4$date <- as.numeric(as.Date(test_4$date,
                                format = "%Y-%m"))
```

I also tried the following, as my date column's class is "character" :

```
 test_4$date <- as.Date(test_4$date,
                               format = "%Y-%m", tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"), optional     = FALSE)
 class(test_4$date)
```

Seeing I lacked the day, I tried to add one without success as it returned a list of NAs :

```
  as.Date(paste("01", test_4$date, sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I have seen other posts here on this question, so I tried the following :

```
  lubridate::parse_date_time("2022-01", "Ym")
```

Which only delivered one date, not all the dates of my columns.
I also tried the following, it works but gives the months in characters and does not give the format 2022-01 I am searching for :

```
 library(zoo) 
 test_4$date <- as.yearmon(test_4$date, format="%Y-%m")
```

Here is the structure of my dataset test_4 for reproducibility :

```
 structure(list(date = c("2022-11", "2022-10", "2022-09", "2022-08", 
 "2022-07", "2022-06"), production_brute_nucleaire = c(22951.429, 
 21465.026, 19334.531, 19319.365, 19923.664, 21275.248)), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, `lubridate::parse_date_time()` works on my side. But maybe you just forgot to pass `test_4$date` to it (instead of the string)? You can also use the shortcut function `ym()` which is equivalent, and returns a date instead of a datetime (which is more consistent with your input data).

```
d <- data.frame(
    date = c("2022-11", "2022-10", "2022-09", "2022-08", "2022-07", "2022-06"),
    production_brute_nucleaire = c(22951.429, 21465.026, 19334.531, 19319.365, 19923.664, 21275.248)
)
d$date <- ym(d$date)
```

The `date` are now replaced by the parsed dates. Note that, as you don't have a day in your dates, the returned dates are the first day of the month.

```
# d$date is now populated with Date values.
> d$date
[1] "2022-11-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-09-01" "2022-08-01" "2022-07-01"
[6] "2022-06-01"
> str(d$date)
Date[1:6], format: "2022-11-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-09-01" "2022-08-01" "2022-07-01" ...
```